# Why is ReLU a non-linear activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, activation-function, relu

As I understand it, in a deep neural network, we use an activation function  (g) after applying the weights (w) and bias(b) `(z := w * X + b | a := g(z))`. So there is a composition function of `(g o z)` and the activation function makes so our model can learn function other than linear functions. I see that Sigmoid and Tanh activation function makes our model non-linear, but I have some trouble seeing that a ReLu (which takes the max out of 0 and z) can make a model non-linear...

Let's say if every Z is always positive, then it would be as if there was no activation function...

So why does ReLu make a neural network model non-linear?

Comment: Bacause the function is... well... non-linear. Piece-wise linear is enough to make it non-linear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Deciding if a function is linear or not is of course not a matter of opinion or debate; there is a very simple [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) of a linear function, which is roughly:

```
f(a*x + b*y) = a*f(x) + b*f(y)
```

for *every* `x` & `y` in the function domain and `a` & `b` constants.

The requirement "for every" means that, if we are able to find even a single example where the above condition does not hold, then the function is nonlinear.

Assuming for simplicity that `a = b = 1`, let's try `x=-5, y=1` with `f` being the ReLU function:

```
f(-5 + 1) = f(-4) = 0
f(-5) + f(1) = 0 + 1 = 1
```

so, for these `x` & `y` (in fact for every `x` & `y` with `x*y < 0`) the condition `f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)` does not hold, hence the function is nonlinear...

The fact that we may be able to find *subdomains* (e.g. both `x` and `y` being either negative or positive here) where the linearity condition holds is what defines some functions (such as ReLU) as [*piecewise*-linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function), which are still nonlinear nevertheless.

Now, to be fair to your question, if in a particular application the inputs happened to be *always* either all positive or all negative, then yes, in this case the ReLU would in practice end up behaving like a linear function. But for neural networks this is not the case, hence we can rely on it indeed to provide our necessary non-linearity...

Comment: Thanks for such an explanation, could you elaborate a bit on your last remarks "But for neural networks, this is not the case"...

Comment: @KhalidSaifullah inputs to NN layers are never always positive or always negative